# How to find who cited a researcher the most

Tags: research-process, citations

I'm doing some history of science research. I want to build networks of researchers that cite each other (or otherwise do similar research).

I'd like to search: **For a researcher X, find which *researcher* has cited them most frequently**.

Is there some tool that can do this kind of thing? I've tried Google Scholar and Web of Knowledge.

Comment: At least two people down-voted, but didn't explain why.  I'm guessing it's because the poster didn't do enough to find out on their own.  Come on, guys. A blind downvote is not helpful.

Comment: Thanks, I'm also surprised. I've tried Scholar and WoK. They let you search "which paper cites this paper" but it's not clear how to search "which _researcher_ cites this researcher/paper the most".

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Google scholar is your best tool and friend. It will tell you how many times a paper was cited and by which papers.

Here is the help site, it is directed towards your own papers but once you check any paper you can see the cites. https://www.google.com/intl/en/scholar/citations.html#citations

You can search for any paper or topic and under each result, besides the star symbol and " it says '*cited by/citado por*' and a number, that tells you how many people cited the material in other materials, and if you click on it you will get a list of all the other materials that cited it. The name of the researchers are under the titles. You can do a discrimination analysis based on the papers with more cites. Which you can get the numbers for in the statistics section top left.

Other option, is the '*related articles/articulos relacionados*'right to the 'cited by', that one open a page with all articles that are related by citation.

Besides that, you can go top left on the 3 lines symbol to open the list and go to '*statistics*' for the  whole list of publications related and how many times it was used/cited by who. You can sort it too by field.

Comment: Thanks. I know this feature, but it doesn't let you see which _researcher_ cites a paper or researcher the most.

Comment: @Smind It actually does. Search for any paper or topic and under each result, besides the star and "  it says 'cited by/citado por' and a number, that tells you how many people cited the material in other materials, and if you click on it you will get a list of all the other materials that cited it. The name of the researchers are under the titles. You can do a discrimination analysis based on the papers with more cites.  Which you can get the numbers for in the statistics section top left.

Comment: Thanks. I can now see the number of times a paper was cited by a researcher by using the "search within citing articles" feature and searching for "author:,name.". But this only works if I already know the author's name. I'm still not sure what you're suggesting. Can you elaborate?

Comment: @Smind Sure. Ill try to clarify and expand the answer

Answer (score 1):

Recently discovered a "top citing researchers" feature on ResearchGate.  Unfortunately, RG doesn't have complete data, but it might be a start.

Comment: Thanks, that's more like what I need :) Unfortunately it only shows you researchers who have a Research Gate profile but lots of the people I'm looking at are dead (and haven't uploaded their papers either).

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately, if you want a complete data set for some rigorous study, you'll probably have to pull from several sources, do some manual clean-up, and reverse-engineer the connections.